# ModRewrite - How to configure .htaccess for mod_rewrite for SEO purposes

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo

I'm trying to make some improvements to my e-commerce site to have better Search Engine Optimization.  One of the more important things is to setup the product to not use the old:

/detail.php?pid=367

Instead we have setup 8 top level categories with 3 sub categories below each of the 8 top level cats.

So for example, one of those categories would look like thisL

/safety-cabinets-fluid-handling/fluid-drum-carts/

Now what I would like to do is have folders below these categories for each product within.  Such as:

/safety-cabinets-fluid-handling/fluid-drum-carts/Lubrigard-Handling-Cart/

My thinking is probably that the best way would be to include the product ID at the end, so it would be this:

/safety-cabinets-fluid-handling/fluid-drum-carts/Lubrigard-Handling-Cart/856

Does this make sense?  And what would I put in the .htaccess in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have any URL structure as long as the pattern is found in the ID, not in the URL structure, which is the normal method.

In your question, the pattern could be the fact that the ID is numeric, so it can be captured from any URL that holds it, regardless of it's structure. For example:

`http://example.com/cat1/cat2/ID/cat3` or

`http://example.com/cat2/ID/cat3/cat1`

makes no difference for a rule that captures a numeric string in any position, like this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /([\d]+)/? 
RewriteRule .*  detail.php?pid=%1  [L,QSA]
```

It will pass silently the ID in the incoming URL to the script, like this:

`http://example.com/detail.php?pid=ID`

Of course, there can't be any other numeric string before the ID in the URL.

However, if you still want the ID to be fixed in the last position in the URL, just replace the above rule set with this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/([0-9]+)/?$
RewriteRule .*  detail.php?pid=%1  [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Looks good, and I'm attempting to implement, couple questions.
1) What is the [L,QSA] for?
2) It seems like its only taking the last number in this one:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*([\d]+)/?$

My number ranges are from 1 to up to 3000.

Comment: `QSA` is the `Query String Append` flag and does what it says when a query string is added in the rule. The `+` in `([\d]+)` means there has to be at least 1 digit with no maximum. Then, all numbers in the 1 to 3000 range are matched by the condition.

Comment: Well, for some reason its not working.  It only taking the last digit.

Comment: ¿When, when the number is in the last position? Please copy-paste the entered URL and your .htaccess file contents.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /([0-9]+)/?

Comment: I got it to work using that line there.  The only issue is that if my product url looks like this:

/safety-cabinets-fluid-handling/ifh-fluid-carts/21-foot-cord-reel/100/

then it uses the first numbers it sees, instead of just the last set (some of my products have numbers in their titles, as we sell machienry parts...  Also forgot to mention [\d] wasn't working, i replaced with [0-9]

Comment: Hence my note `Of course, there can't be any other numeric string before the ID in the URL` in the answer. That can be fixed, but, again, where is it in the URL, in the last position?

Comment: https://www.lubrigard.com/safety-cabinets-fluid-handling/ifh-fluid-carts/Dessicant-Mini-Breather-2%22(W)-X-3%22(H)/100/

Looks like its working fine, even with numeric chars before the final / /

Comment: @MichaelDeMutis Updated my answer for ID in the last URL position. The [\d] should work, but replaced it for digits as you did just in case.